# Print Message and Ask For User Input In R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a html report using rmarkdown and need to check the input data set for certain conditions. If a condition has been met, I need to print a message to the console and ask the user if they would like to continue or not. Following is the chunk of code in my rmarkdown file as a reproducible example:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("A", "B", "C", "no", "no", "no"), nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
names(data) <- c("Name", "Include")

if(nrow(data) > 0 ){
    message("Following are names to not include:\n",
       paste0(capture.output(data[c("Name", "Include")]), collapse = "\n"))

   continue <- readline(prompt = "Do you wish to continue? Type y or n and press enter:")

}
```
````

I would like the following to be printed to the console:

```
Following are names to not include:   
  Name   Include   
1    A        no   
2    B        no
3    C        no
Do you wish to continue? Type y or n and press enter:
```

When I do this outside of the rmarkdown file, the desired message and question prints to the console. However, when I do this within the rmarkdown file, only

```
"Do you wish to continue? Type y or n and press enter:"
```

prints to the console.

Comment: When you render the R Markdown file, you get an HTML document (I assume, since that's the default and you didn't say otherwise).  All R code in a document is executed, the results are captured, and then a static HTML file is generated.  You should look into Shiny for making interactive web pages.

Comment: Yes html, which was specified in the first line of my question. We are not interested in an interactive web page, we looked down that avenue and for the time frame we have, this is the best way to go. Until this message, everything has worked fine.

Comment: @Kr32 you can't execute R code from a R Markdown file rendered to HTML. You can't pass an input via HTML to your R code, because the HTML file is a static representation of the code/output in your markdown.

Comment: @Mako212 I am able to pass an input to my R code, if I include the readline function in my code it asks if the user wants to continue and depending on if y or n is typed in it does two different things.

Comment: That is because R (the program) is executing the command.  An HTML is read by a browser, which does not execute R code.  Without something like Shiny (JavaScript run by the browser, R run by a server), this won't work.

Comment: @Kr32 Your R markdown (what you see in the browser) is essentially equivalent to printing out your R code and output on a piece of paper. You can't pass user input to it.